# passing target to SUBDIRS in Makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, autotools

Let's say I have a makefile.am with

```
   SUBDIRS = a . b c
```

I want to call the Makefile in a/ passing a target, and ONLY to the makefile in a/ (not ., b/ or c/).

Is there a way to do it, in case even not using SUBDIRS for a/ ?

Comment: Your question doesn't have enough detail.  Is there a reason that writing `a: ; cd $@ && $(MAKE) target` won't work?  Plus `.PHONY: a` of course.

Comment: @MadScientist: no, there is no reason, apart the fact that is ugly.

Comment: Well, you asked "is there a way", not "is there a pretty way" :).  You'll have to define what you mean by "ugly".  For instance if you provide an actual example of what you're doing and point out specifically which parts of it you think are ugly we might be able to provide nicer options.

Comment: @MadScientist: sorry, I didn't mean to say it's not good. I was just pointing out it's ugly, but at the moment is the only one suggestion I got, so I'll stick to it :-)

Comment: I think @MadScientist's comment should be posted as an answer. To my knowledge there is no way to do this built into Automake with nice syntax; probably because Automake doesn't consider it recommended practice.